# In ARCGIS 10.5 mxd I need to put definition query for one layer as Current Year in Year fields , What i need to set the query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, mxd, publishing

I have a feature class and related info in another table, the table having fields as Year, Year having values like - 2016,2017,2018,2019... Presently I Put the definition query for table Year = 2018 after that I have joined table to feature and published map service and the results perfectly fine. for next year also I need to change year=2019. So that without changing the code every time, I required based on the system date need to change the year. Please provide the code for that how to get the date in select by attribute

Year field is Integer

The Table is SQL Table which is not registered as versioned

Comment: What is field type? -  `date` or `integer`

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer is the SQL table so I required to use as `Year = Year(getdate())`

Whereas in GIS Table use  `Yearfieldname = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `CURRENT_DATE` to return current date then (perhaps) you have to transform it to `integer` because looks like it is not `date` type (2016,2017,2018,2019).